# How do I create a Breeze entity of a derived class?

Tags: breeze

In a breeze model with a simple TPH inheritance structure, I can't work out how to correctly create a new breeze entity of a child type.

For example:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte VehicleType { get; set; }
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    // Some extra properties
}
```

The discriminator does not follow the standard Entity Framework approach of using a string value to determine a class's parent so we use some EF FluentAPI to modify the metadata:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>()
                .Map<Car>(m => m.Requires("VehicleType").HasValue((byte)1));
}
```

The default behaviour from the code below appears to create a suitable entity in Breeze but the discriminator value is never set so saving changes to the server results in the persistence of an object of type Vehicle instead of Car.

```
var group = breezeManager.createEntity("Car", {
    Name: 'My car'
    // If the line below is omitted, VehicleType is saved
    // to the server with a value of 0
    ,VehicleType: 1
});
breezeManager.saveChanges();
```

Although this appears to be a question about the behaviour of the client-side component of Breeze, it might be relevant that we are using Breeze to store into a database that is not accessed via the Entity Framework (we just generate EF metadata for Breeze to consume).

I don't think that the client-side code should have to worry about the implementation of our inheritance discriminators so hopefully there is an alternative to manually setting the value when we create every object.

What is the best way to correctly store the discriminator value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to verify that TPH with byte discriminator value works. The only difference that I notice between my model and yours is that I didn't specify the byte property in mine.

```
public abstract class Airplane
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public byte AirplaneType { get; set; }  //Not required
}

public class Boeing : Airplane
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

Specifying the discriminator in the Fluent API was enough to let EF saves the right value.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realise that was optional but everything works perfectly without it as you suggest.